# Determine viewcontroller's view size dynamically on viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I've searched a lot about how can I determine the actual view size dynamically in the viewDidLoad method.

Here is my approach which seems to be work on both iOS6 and iOS7 with both Landscape and Portrait mode.

Is there a better solution for that?

Here is my code:

```
- (CGSize)actualSize {
    CGFloat widht;
    CGFloat height;

    // Determin height and widht
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight ||  orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        widht = kHeightSelfView;
        height = kWidthSelfView;
    } else {
        widht = kWidthSelfView;
        height = kHeightSelfView;
    }

    // Determin navigationbar height
    CGFloat navigationBarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden ? .0f : (MIN(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width));

    // Determin navigationbar height
    CGFloat statusbarHeight = [DeviceCompatibility isIOS7] ? (MIN(SharedApplication.statusBarFrame.size.width, SharedApplication.statusBarFrame.size.height)) : .0f;

    return CGSizeMake(widht, height - navigationBarHeight - statusbarHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically you should only perform view-based geometry in viewWillAppear.  Your view's frame is not yet set in viewDidLoad, but it will be set correctly before viewWillAppear is called.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I create my views inside the viewDidLoad and I don't want to declare ivars for every small view to set their frames later in the viewWillAppear. What do you think about that?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of picking height & width, you can pick the frame of view like this:

```
// Adjusts the frame of the child view.
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    CGRect linkedFrame = scene.view.frame;
    linkedFrame.origin.x -= frame.origin.x;
    linkedFrame.origin.y -= frame.origin.y;
```

and then you can make them flexible so that they will resize properly :

```
// The scene's main view must be made flexible so it will resize properly
        // in the container.
        scene.view.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
                                       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
```

Let me know if this is not what you need :)

Comment: Not exactly but I learned from your code. Thanks for your comment.